# Generate docx on Javascript Rhino

Tags: javascript, docx, rhino, servicenow

I am trying to complete an impossible mission.
I need to generate docx documents on ServiceNow (server side) which implements the Javascript Rhino engine. Doing do on the client side is super easy, I usually use docxtemplater or similar great libraries. The problem here is that we need to build it on the server and using ServiceNow technologies (script includes, etc).
That said, I am trying to port the client docxtemplater version but I am struggling because on the server there is no concept of DOM.
At the same time, using the server side version is difficult because ServiceNow does not use Node js but Rhino, and all libraries out there are based on Node.
The best thing I was able to do using vanilla js is to generate a data uri that, when downloaded from the browser, returns a docx document, but I was wandering if anyone has any suggestions.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: docxtemplater doesn't need the DOM to work. Please share a [mcve] of the code to show the issue you're having.

Comment: Not even the browser version does need the dom? I will update the code ASAP

Comment: I've used docxtemplater in node exclusively. https://docxtemplater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generate.html --- It only needs pizzip to work.

Comment: The problem in my case is that I need to convert all these dependencies into JS Rhino compatible code..and also servicenow compatible...which is a nightmare

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to accomplish this. One is to embrace the nightmare, and either transpile the OpenXml JS libs to ES5 compatibility or rewrite them. The other is to create a MS Word template, encode as Base64 text (as it's zipped XML) and save in ServiceNow, then unzip and traverse the XML using the ServiceNow [XMLDocument2](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/quebec/server/no-namespace/c_XMLDocument2ScopedAPI) library to update the text. Finally, you re-zip and save the file to create the updated OpenXml document.

The second solution requires you to get JSZip in ES5.

The source code to my solution is currently proprietary and I am not free to share it, but it can be done. Just make sure you've got a big enough budget, as it's not trivial and takes a fair amount of time to implement.